# Access Model Instances from Template without custom filter

Tags: python, django

I have yet to see anybody implement this pattern and am eager to learn if it's even technically viable. Let me provide an example of what the pattern would look like using a custom filter:

In this example, the "get_widget" filter will look for MyWidget objects with the name or key passed in as the first argument.

**Template Logic**

```
{% get_widget "whizbang" as item %}
<h1>{{item.name}}</h1>

{% get_widget "1234" as item %}
<h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
```

**Custom Filter**

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_widget(context, widget_name):

    try:
        return MyWidget.objects.get(name=widget_name)
    except MyWidget.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

But that seems rather hideous.

What I'd like to see is something a little more dyanmic:

Example:
Retrieve an instance of MyWidget based on its name being "whizbang" or, alternatively, using it's key. 
In the template:

```
<h1>{{MyWidget.whizbang}}</h1>
<h1>{{MyWidget.1234}}</h1>
```

The question is twofold:

1. Would it be possible to pass in a singleton/factory to the
   request_context
2. Is there a Python mechanism to "intercept" a method
   call and interpret it before it's executed?

Answer (score 0):

After sifting through the Python docs it looks like a combination of `__getattrr__()` and passing in a class name is all that was required. My apologies for answering my own question. Hopefully this will be useful for someone else.

**Template**

```
{{ Menus.HeyDude.DoSomething }}
```

**Class**

```
from mycode import Menu
class MenuFactory():
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return Menu.object.get(name=name)
        except Menu.DoesNotExist:
            raise AttributeError
```

**Middlewear context processor**

```
from mycode import MenuFactory
def context_processor(request):

    return_val = {}

    # Add all of the factories
    return_val['Menus'] = MenuFactory
    return return_val
```